# Is there a way to launch an application in a new worspace by using a shortcut?

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome3

So by pressing <kbd>super</kbd> you can search for an application and open it by pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Is there a way to open that new application in a different worspace by holding a key (like searching for something on a browser and holding <kbd>alt</kbd> while pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> to open it in a new tab)?